# Java Object creating a different Class object

Tags: java

I'll just start by saying that I am a new to Java programming. I've got this problem:

I have this class:

```
public class Unit
{
    public boolean status;
    public Unit()
    {
         status=true;
    }
    public boolean getstatus(){
         return status;
    }
    public void setstatus(boolean pStatus){
         status=pStatus;
    }
}
```

And i need a second class called **TestUnit** that, when i use it to create a object, unpon creation it creates also a **Unit** class.

How can i do this? Help would be appreciated.

P.S.: I'm working with Bluej.

Answer (score 0):

If your `TestUnit` class is in the same package, then it can just create a new `Unit` instance like this:

```
Unit u = new Unit();
```

But they ought really to be in different packages, for instance

```
com.giaky.unit
com.giaky.unit.test
```

In that case, you need to *import* the class into your `TestUnit` class. You do that with a line at the top of the file, just under the `package` statement, like this:

```
import com.giaky.unit.Unit;
```

After that, you can create instances of your `Unit` class just as if it were in the same package, with

```
Unit u = new Unit();
```

Your IDE will help you with all of this: it should be able to help you move the classes to different packages, if needed, and also to import classes from one package into another.

Importing is something you'll need a lot, every time you use a class from the JDK libraries.

Comment: So the **TestUnit** class should look like this? 
    public class testUnit
    {
        public testUnit()
        {
            Unit unit_2 = new Unit();
        }
    }

Comment: Yes, that's right (although obviously there's not much point unless you do something with it after you've created it!). You might want to have a `private` field of your `TestUnit` class that stores an instance of `Unit` (or you might not, depending on what you're doing).

Comment: Also, make sure you call it `TestUnit` (initial caps) rather than `testUnit` (initial lower case). Class names ought to start with capital letters (though it's not strictly speaking an error not to do so).

Answer (score 0):

Are you look for this?

```
public class TestUnit{
   private Unit unit;

   public TestUnit(){
       unit = new Unit();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class TestUnit{
     private Unit unit;
     public TestUnit(){
       this.unit=new Unit();}
   }
   }
```

//you can add other methods and variables as needed :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
public class TestUnit {
    //You can create a reference to handle your Unit instance
    private Unit myunit;

    //Provide a constructor to assign a unit you create
    public TestUnit(Unit myunit) {
        this.myunit = myunit;
    }

    //Or provide a default constructor which instances a default one
    public TestUnit() {
        this.myunit = new Unit();
    }

}
```

I think that is a way you can handle, I know very good answers will come, but this is my approach according to your description :)

Regards and happy coding :).